# Pushforward along finite morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

For a closed immersion $i$ of schemes, the coherent sheaf $i_\ast\mathcal{O}_Y$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras is generated by a (single) global section. Now, let $f:Y\to X$ be a surjective finite morphism between Noetherian schemes.

> Is the coherent sheaf $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_Y$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras generated by its global sections? If that is not satisfied in general, is it known when it is?

References or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost never the case for example when both $X,Y$ are projective varieties. Of course, everything is globally generated if $X$ (and then $Y$) is affine. In the projective case, if $\deg f>1$ and assuming both smooth, we have $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus E$ where $E$ is a rank $\deg f-1$ vector bundle on $X$ and $H^0(E)=0$, so it can not be globally generated.

Comment: Thank you! My motivation for the question is an attempt to understand a proof in a paper, as detailed [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/266467/when-is-a-coherent-subsheaf-determined-by-its-global-sections).

Comment: @Mohan   Do we know higher cohomology of $E$?  and is $E$ always  locally free? Thanks

Comment: For a finite map, there is no higher cohomology, since those maps are affine. No, $E$ may not be locally free in general, but in the above case I was thinking of smooth curves. $E$ is a vector bundle if and only if $f$ is in addition flat.